# add event listener to multiple divs with same class in a container

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a 16x16 grid whereby I want to add an event listener to every div in this grid. First, I selected all divs in the container using document.querySelectorAll(). Then I looped over this list using forEach(). This did not work so I tried container.childNodes.forEach(), but still faced the same issue. Would appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const gridItem = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").forEach(gridItem => gridItem.addEventListener("click", myFunc));



function makeGrid(rows,cols) {
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows",rows);
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols",cols);

    for (let i = 0; i < (rows*cols); i++) {
        let gridItem = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(gridItem).classList.add("grid-item");
    }
}

makeGrid(16,16);


function myFunc() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the content of `gridItem` to be after the `.querySelector().forEach()` construct?

Comment: why would you not just add it when you create the element?

Comment: _"This did not work so I tried container.childNodes.forEach()"_ -> _"[Describe the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are you running this code after the DOM has been loaded, so that there are elements with the class `.grid-item` that will be returned?

Comment: You select the elements before you make the grid.... :) It is like trying to eat a pizza before it is made. It is not going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your logic.

1. Select an element
2. Find all the .grid-item elements
3. Define a function that creates grid-item
4. Call the function that creates grid-item

So with that logic, you are clearly not going to find any elements. You need to create the grid-item elements before you select them. You also are not adding the class to the element correctly

So changing the order:

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log("hello", this);
}

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
makeGrid(16, 16);
const gridItem = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").forEach(gridItem => gridItem.addEventListener("click", myFunc));


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    const gridItem = document.createElement("div");
    gridItem.classList.add("grid-item");
    gridItem.textContent = i + 1;
    container.appendChild(gridItem)
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  --grid-cols: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  gap: .1em;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: .2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

But why not bind the events when you create the element?

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log("hello", this);
}

const container = document.querySelector(".container");

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    const gridItem = document.createElement("div");
    gridItem.classList.add("grid-item");
    gridItem.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
    gridItem.textContent = i + 1;
    container.appendChild(gridItem)
  }
}

makeGrid(16, 16);
```

```css
.container {
  --grid-cols: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  gap: .1em;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: .2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

or just use event delegation

```js
function myFunc(event) {
  console.log("hello", event.target.closest('.grid-item'));
}

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.addEventListener("click", myFunc);


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    const gridItem = document.createElement("div");
    gridItem.classList.add("grid-item");
    gridItem.textContent = i + 1;
    container.appendChild(gridItem)
  }
}

makeGrid(16, 16);
```

```css
.container {
  --grid-cols: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  gap: .1em;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: .2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: what a newbie mistake, thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

You just have things out of order. Create your grid first, then apply the event listeners. As it is, it's looping through an empty array trying to apply listeners.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    let gridItem = document.createElement("div");
    gridItem.innerHTML = "grid item";
    container.appendChild(gridItem).classList.add("grid-item");
  }
}

makeGrid(16, 16);
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").forEach(gridItem => gridItem.addEventListener("click", myFunc));

function myFunc() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this solved it

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, consider marking it as the solution by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a listener for each element. You can just create one listener on the parent element and conditionally call your code in the function:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
// add a single listener to the parent element of the grid items
container.addEventListener("click", myFunc);

// -- snip --

function myFunc(event) {
    // only run the code if the clicked element matches the selector
    if (event.target.matches(".grid-item")) {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

See also: [`Element.matches()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)